# Testing Meteor packages with Velocity?

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

Velocity is an amazing testing framework for Meteor and I am currently using it to test my application code.

Now I added a local package to the app, but I don't know how (or if) I can test the package with Velocity, too. I would like to drop tinyTest in favor for a consistent testing framework - Velocity.

Is it possible to test packages with Velocity? How should the file structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to test packages with sanjo:jasmine. It works in nearly the same way as with TinyTest. You can find all information to get started in the [sanjo:jasmine README](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/blob/master/README.md#testing-a-package). There is also an [example package](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/tree/master/test-app/packages/package-to-test). To run the tests, use the commands from the README.

If you need additional information, let me know.

Comment: How about with `xolvio:cucumber`?

Comment: is there any way to include the (local) package testing in the default runner? manually running the CLI is a bit of a drag.