# How can I limit which Velocity unit tests run at a given time for a large Meteor application?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

This is somewhat of a follow up to another question here: [Testing Meteor packages with Velocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896700/testing-meteor-packages-with-velocity)

Situation:
We're developing a meteor app for which different developers are working on different packages.  It will be a very large app. We want to be able to run tests across the entire app (default Velocity), but also be able to just run the unit tests on a given package while working on it.  In other situations (using Gulp in a MEAN stack for example), setting up specific

Problem:
Although there is some documentation (https://meteor-testing.readme.io/docs/jasmine-testing-a-meteor-package) on running package-only tests, there seems to be some odd behaviour.  Namely, if I move tests into a folder structure within the package, the whole-app test runs appear to see the tests (the files show up in the in-browser Velocity test file listing), but the tests themselves don't appear to run.

In contrast, if I use the Velocity CLI (or Meteor CLI with required env vars etc) to target just the package, then the package tests do run, but the app seems to be broken.  The implication is that I need to run both the app tests and the package tests independently to get full test coverage... this begs the question of what would happen if moved to an CI system.

Assumptions:
I assume that what I'm aiming for is readily achievable - namely that the entire app + package tests can all be run at once, but (via some extra CLI configuration) tests can also be limited to just the package currently worked on.  Presumably, there are either some settings that I'm missing, or some error in how I'm setting up my package definitions.  Any pointers or clarifications appreciated.